# Going from step to next step during check-out sometimes gets stuck for minutes at a time

Tags: performance

```
Magento 1.9.1
Porto theme
SSD VPS with 6 GB RAM; Cores: 8
```

People told me they have experienced this on my website but I haven't actually seen this myself until last week for the first time. Now I've seen it happen at least 4 times within a week. When you are going through the order process and click whatever button to proceed - it just gives you the circle that goes round and round for minutes and it will actually take 5 minutes or so to go to the next step. There seems to be no rhyme or reason to this - it happens intermittently and at different places of the check-out.

Comment: When this happens are there any console logs? Can you see which file/request is taking so long?

Comment: @ Ben Crook How to I pull up the console logs?

Comment: That depends on your browser, if you right click anywhere on the page and click on inspect element or something similar. You should then get a tab/window and in that it should reference console somewhere.